# Is there a way to refresh lower environment (SIT, UAT) database from Production in Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

Can we refresh Snowflake Database of lower environment (SIT, UAT) from production?
In MS SQL Server, we simply restore the backup from Prod to SIT/UAT. Do we have similar options available in Snowflake? My need is to refresh all the Schema of Snowflake at least. Kindly share yore advise.

Answer (score 1):

[Conquering DevOps for Data](https://www.snowflake.com/guides/conquering-devops-data):

> **Rapidly seed preproduction environments with production data**
>
> Snowflake offers two ways to seed a preproduction environment with production data. Secure Data Sharing is used when the environments are on separate Snowflake accounts, and zero-copy cloning is used when the environments are on the same account.
>
> **Secure Data Sharing enables access to live data from a provider account to one or many consumer accounts and is typically used to
> share data with partners or with other departments.**
>
> **Zero-copy cloning creates a copy of live data instantly in metadata, without the
> need to duplicate or move data, saving storage costs and time.**

More at: [CREATE  … CLONE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-clone.html) and [Cloning Considerations](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/object-clone.html)

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, when you want to create another environment (preprod, uat, int, dev...), zero copy cloning generates a problem: you get a new database with objects (tables, views, etc) that belong to production roles. It is then necessary to change all the owner roles of the objects, which is not an easy task.

Stef

Comment: After having resolving the ownership problem, you must re-apply your RBAC model. You must re-execute your SQL code to grant rights to the Privilege Access roles.

In conclusion : a lot of work :-)